Why is RNASpades giving three FASTA output files instead of only one?
I'm running RNASpades for de-novo transcriptome assembly in the Galaxy workflow manager
. Instead of giving only one output of assembled Transcripts, it is giving three FASTA outputs namely:

Transcripts (37,741 sequences)
Soft-filtered Transcripts (46,250 sequences)
Hard-filtered Transcripts (29,808 sequences)

Can I interpret that the Transcripts file represents some kind of optimization between soft-filtered and hard-filtered transcripts? if it helps, RNASpades selected two kmer values automatically when assembling the Transcripts.

I have never used this tool before, but a simple search for it returns its github page and documentation. The files are explained in the relevant section:

rnaSPAdes output
rnaSPAdes outputs one main FASTA file named transcripts.fasta. The corresponding file with paths in the assembly_graph.fastg is transcripts.paths.
In addition rnaSPAdes outputs transcripts with different level of filtration into /: - hard_filtered_transcripts.fasta - includes only long and reliable transcripts with rather high expression. - soft_filtered_transcripts.fasta - includes short and low-expressed transcripts, likely to contain junk sequences.
We recommend using the main transcripts.fasta file in case you don't have any specific needs for your projects.


Great! Thanks. Actually the same is also available in Galaxy. But the issue is that why is the number of sequences in Transcripts lower than Soft-filtered transcripts if they were "filtered"? Definately Hard-filtered transcripts should have the least number of sequences because it is "Hard Filtered". Maybe it has something to do deeper in the algorithm.

@EshaanIITM Because "soft_filtered_transcripts.fasta - includes short and low-expressed transcripts, likely to contain junk sequences". So of course it has more. Don't look at the name, read the description in my answer. Everything is filtered somehow, including Transcripts.fasta. Then, you have the "soft" filtered, which is more inclusive and has more results, and the "hard" filtered which is more restrictive and has fewer.
